# Render overflow when TextField is in focus

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have Column with the TextField and Flexible inside it. Flexible consist of ListView displaying the list of hero characters.
When I get to focus on TextField, the display shows Render Overflow by x pixels. What to do to avoid this?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            controller: tc,
          ),
        ),
        new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.67,
              child: checkList(context, characterDataWrapper), //MY LISTVIEW
            ),
            new Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: new Container(),
            ),
            new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: getData,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text("Click"),
                  ),
                ]),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question that allows to reproduce and a screenshot of the phone with the error

Comment: Please provide your code and also post image what you need to show.

Comment: I cannot upload image because my reputation is low. 

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is in

```
new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.67,
              child: checkList(context, characterDataWrapper), //MY LISTVIEW
            ),
```

Please provide your code or any screenshot of it.

I think you have a textfield at the top,
a Listview at middle and a button at the bottom.

Then you may try like this...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "I am the TextField"),
        ),
        new Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("Some Text"),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        new RaisedButton(onPressed: () {})
      ],
    );
  }
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: It worked. Kudos to you.! I used `Expanded` instead of `Flexible` but it worked.